# ionic2: API response data undefined?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic2-providers

I'm using `ionic2`, I want to make login request to api server, but I have response => `undefined` 
this is the code in provider:

```
loginUser(email, password, macId, token) {
   let userObject = {
       "email": email,
       "password": password,
       "mac" : macId,
       "token" : token
   }
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    console.log('object: ',userObject);
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, userObject, {headers:headers})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())    
  }
```

and this is the code in `login page`:

```
loginUser(email,password) {
console.log('email: ',email,'password: ',password);
if(!this.loginForm.valid){
 this.submitAttempt = true;
} else {
 this.submitAttempt = false;
 this.deviceInfo.macId = this.device.uuid;
 this.fcm.getToken().then(token=>{
   this.token = token;
   });
 this.userProvider.loginUser(email,password,this.deviceInfo.macId,this.token)
 .subscribe(data=> {
   alert("data is "+data);
 },
   (err)=>{
     alert("err"+err);
   }
 )


}
```

the output should be:

```
{
  msg : "SyGgTmNHxJcZFYJu6RootUHAqzdkhPNzsTGJHipeBZQSN8nHdbHga4gQ3jENesNPsK5tdtGKlmUa5g3cIVDO4ZqqENd5uPizwgWkq6z3CyUXAhyns8PTnNPwax7lgKRiY7I67qmiPCpZdwu2Kh5v7U"
}
```

but the actual output:

```
data: "undefined"
```

what should I do?

Comment: so the error output u get happens here: `this.userProvider.loginUser(email,password,this.deviceInfo.macId,this.token)
 .subscribe(data=> {
   alert("data is "+data);
 },`?

Comment: what is your `this.loginUrl`?

Comment: @ewizard http://fashion.fatimabalhaddad.com/public/api/login

Comment: log `response.json()` from `loginUser` function and see if it is undefined there....also instead of doing `return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, userObject, {headers:headers})
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())` try `return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, userObject, {headers:headers})` without the `map` and instead of `.subscribe` with the `userProvider`...use `.then(data => { ...`

Comment: `subscribe` is for `observables` and im pretty sure `this.http.post` returns a promise which uses `then` instead of `subscribe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `map` it, just `return` the `promise` that is returned by `this.http.post` in your `userProvider` function and use `.then()` where you are calling it to get the data:

```
loginUser(email, password, macId, token) {
   let userObject = {
       "email": email,
       "password": password,
       "mac" : macId,
       "token" : token
   }
   var headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   console.log('object: ',userObject);
   return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, userObject, {headers:headers});  
}
```

and...

```
loginUser(email,password) {
  console.log('email: ',email,'password: ',password);
  if(!this.loginForm.valid){
  this.submitAttempt = true;
} else {
  this.submitAttempt = false;
  this.deviceInfo.macId = this.device.uuid;
  this.fcm.getToken().then(token=>{
    this.token = token;
  });
this.userProvider.loginUser(email,password,this.deviceInfo.macId,this.token)
     .then(data=> {
       alert("data is "+data);
     },
       (err)=>{
         alert("err"+err);
       }
     )
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you
I removes map and use subscribe instead of then because I had error with then >> it is not decleared, what is the problem!